# XML to Database, what route should I take?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

I have access to an traffic data server from where I get XML files with the information that I need. (Example: Point A to Point B: travel time 20 min, distance 18 miles, etc).

I download the XML file (which is archived), extract it, then process it and store it into a DB. I only allow for the download of the XML file per request but only if 5 minutes have passed from last download. The XML on the traffic server gets updated every 30 seconds to maybe 5 minutes. During the 5 minute period any user requesting the webpage will retrieve the data from the DB (no update) therefore limiting the number of requests made to the traffic server.

My problem with my current approach is that when I get new XML file the whole process takes some time (3-7 seconds) and that makes the user wait too much before getting anything. However, when no XML download is needed and all the data gets displayed straight from the DB the process is very fast.
The archived XML is about 100-200KB, while the unarchived one is about 2MB. The XML file contains traffic data from 3 or 4 states, while I only need the data for one state. That is why I currently use the DB method.

Is this approach a good one? I was wondering if I should just extract the data directly from the downloaded XML file for every request and limit somehow how often the XML file gets downloaded from the traffic server. Or, can anyone point me to a better way?

Sample of the XML file
[image: sample of the XML file]

This is how it looks on my website
[image: This is how it looks on my website]

Comment: Define "good".  What measure is important to you?

Comment: I thought of the CRON job route but that means that no matter if any user requests data it will be updated. Right now it only gets updated if it is requested and if no more than 5 minutes passed since the last update.

Good would be to have a faster access even when new XML is requested!

Comment: You could create a CRON job that periodically accesses the XML file, parses it and stores the data into the database. Then the users would only access the database data. That way there wouldn't be any noticeable delay when users access the data.

Comment: To be honest 3-7 seconds is not that big of a deal if the user is notified of the action taking place (such a "loading..." status bar or spinner). You could use AJAX to achieve that.

Comment: @Cristian What if every request reads from DB but when you read expired data it also triggers XML download? Multiple requests (during download) will still read from DB.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - I currently use that approach with the difference being that expired data is triggered before the user gets anything, therefore the delay. If I understand right, you mean to give expired data to the user and then in background request an update for the XML. How can I achieve this? AJAX? But wouldn't this approach require that specific user to reload in order to get the new data?

Comment: Not AJAX, server side. You give back _old_ data and then you trigger an update server side (user won't get that). Next time (or next user) will get updated one. If you reduce expiration to 2.5/3 minutes then  you'll have more or less same update time (but without delays).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I am not allowed to download the XML files less than 5 minutes by the server admin. How would I trigger the server side update? exec or shell_exec? But after thinking of this, I doubt it will work nice since the first user won't get new data. For example, if no one makes a request during the night the data will be at least 3-5 hours old. When a new user does the request they'll get very old data and therefore would need a new reload.

Comment: @Cristian true, server side _rules_ may _decide_ to serve a request synchronously (and user, that particular time, will need to wait). It depends how often you will have users to query data (1 wait every 100 requests **may** be acceptable). If this delay is always unacceptable and your web site admin lets you schedule tasks then you may follow what Tomas said (cron job). In case you can't don't forget also a _fake_ request may start your task (triggered, for example, by a client side repetitive fake AJAX query). In this case auto-refresh will occur if there is at least one logged in user...

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the XML each time it changes.

But only if you've got active users in the next period of time it takes to download the files.

As you can't foresee the future, you don't know whether or not you'll get a request of a user within the next 7 seconds.

You can however possibly find out with a HEAD request if the XML file has been updated.

So you could create yourself a service that is downloading from the remote system the XML each time it changes. In case the date is indeed not needed that often, you can configure that service to not check and/or download that often.

The rest of your system can be independent to it as long as you can learn about the best configuration of the download service by statistical analysis of your users behavior.

If you need this even more real-time you need to configure the new services based on changing data from the other system and then you need to start to interchange data bidirectionally between those two systems which is more complicated and can lead to more side-effects. But from the numbers you give, this level of detail probably isn't needed anyway, so I won't care about it.